# In Root A, did Hide feed himself to Kaneki so that he would heal?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Hide started bleeding shortly after Kaneki woke up, however, Kaneki had passed out from blood loss and was having difficulty healing. 
Then there's the weird dream Kaneki had that makes me believe that maybe he was, like, sleep-feeding or something.

Did Hide maybe feed part of himself to Kaneki so that Kaneki would heal instead of dying?

Answer (score 1):

Hide let kaneki eat him so kaneki could regain his strength and the 2nd season of the anime doesnt follow the manga.

Comment: Hi, looks like you posted a new answer even though you already have [an existing answer here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/46498/2516). Unless this is a significantly different answer, consider [edit]ing the older one, then deleting this answer to make the thread clean :)

Answer (score 0):

We wouldn't know for sure because those events took place after he woke up and therefore the answer is not simple or a known fact. Only the writer would know, but my opinion is: no, Hide must have took damage from a ghoul.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site about anime & manga. We're a bit different than conventional forums in that question and answers should be self-contained (not "search on Google for ..."). Personal theory is an acceptable answer provided there are some explanation/sources/references to back up the theory. Meanwhile, consider taking a [tour] to understand how this site works, and enjoy~

Answer (score 0):

This was not shown in the anime nor in the first **Tokyo Ghoul** manga. The answer to this was only revealed in **Tokyo Ghoul:re**.

In **Vol. 15 Chapter 164**,

> a scene was shown in which Kaneki and Hide were talking at the top of a building. Later on, Kaneki **asks Hide to show what he** (Kaneki) **did to him** (Hide). This implies that **Kaneki did attack/mutilate Hide but could not remember it himself**. Also, since Hide did not harbor feelings of anger or regret against Kaneki throughout the manga, it can be said that he either **let Kaneki eat a part of him** or he might have tried to fight back and failed but **forgave Kaneki for what he did**. Personally, I think the former was what happened, given how Nagachika is. [image]